# $.get added to Button.ClientSideEvents.Click doesn't work on second click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
string okumagecmisiStr = string.Format("function(s,e){{ $.get('/GetHazirRapor.ashx?RaporTanimi={0}',function(data){{location.href='{1}'}} );  }}", hrt.ID, hrt.WebRaporLink);

ButtonWebRaporAc.ClientSideEvents.Click = okumagecmisiStr;
```

The above C# code from the codebehind of aspx page is in a callbackpanel.  When the page is loaded, it goes through the callback code, adding the above function to the button.  And it works fine on the first try, going through the handler, then loading the page (with location.).  But if you try to do it again, it will skip the handler, and just go to the page.

How can I make it so it goes to the handler each time?

**UPDATE:**

I went ahead to try the AJAX method, but I am getting stuck with the format of this line in C# not being accepted.

```
string okumagecmisiStr = string.Format("function(s,e) { $.ajax({ url: '/GetHazirRapor.ashx?RaporTanimi={0}', type: 'GET', success: function(data){ location.href='{1}' }, cache: false })", hrt.ID, hrt.WebRaporLink);
```

Am I missing a bracket or comma or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$.get will cache the result. So you will need to disable caching.  I think the only way to set cache to false is to use $.ajax instead like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/GetHazirRapor.ashx?RaporTanimi=",
  "type": "GET",
  success: function(data){
      location.href = ''
  },
  cache: false
});
```

**Upate:**
Your missing a "}" at the end of the function:

```
function(s,e) {{
  $.ajax({{
     url: '/GetHazirRapor.ashx?RaporTanimi={0}', 
     type: 'GET',
     success: function(data) {{
         location.href='{1}'
     }},
     cache: false
  }})
}}
```

Comment: Updated question...check it out please.

Comment: I updated the line of code above with what you suggested, but I am still getting the format error.

Comment: You actually do need the two "{" to escape them. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx

Comment: The new version of what I tried is in my question under update.